# Is there a purchasable copy of the Shulchan Aruch in Hebrew and English?

Tags: halacha, shulchan-aruch

I'm looking to buy an *actual* Shulchan Aruch, not a Kitzur. I already own the Artscroll Kitzur and, while it is an amazing work, doesn't help very much when I want to research the actual halacha, where it comes from, and how it applies to a Sefard like myself. Is there an edition out there which is the whole original Shulchan Aruch by Yosef Karo in Hebrew and English?

Comment: Just realized how weird it is that English versions have been made of all types of halachic works, like Mishna Torah, Sefer HaChinuch, Mishna Berura, (not to mention Talmud Bavli,) but I can't think of a single English version of the Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I want the __source__.

Comment: You might be interested, though, in the many contemporary English books available on pretty much any halachic subject. They usually consist of a summary of the applicable halachos, with useful footnotes telling of the sources in classic sources in shulchan aruch, its commentators, responsa, and contemorary poskim.

Comment: @TK, Welcome (belatedly) to judaism.SE, and thanks very much for these intriguing questions!

Comment: Wikipedia is working on it:
http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch

Comment: Also, if you want the original sources, an English Halachik work might have more information. The shulchan aruch doesn't provide any background, it just states the halacha. (The Beis Yosef was his main work which got into details.) English books often give a full presentation of all the principles and how to apply them nowadays.

Comment: @ArielK - IIRC, the B"Y al ha-Tur was comprised of his actual piskey halacha, and the S"A supposed to be a summary of his B"Y in a shorthand form.

Comment: http://www.shulchanarach.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some partial English translation are available, see here:

http://www.jtsa.edu/x1212.xml#english_translations

But to answer your question, no there is no purchasable Hebrew/English Shulchan Aruch available. (If you just need Orach Chayim, the English translation of the Mishneh Berurah might suffice, although of course it lacks all of the other commentaries)

Answer (score 3):

don't think there's. as jake mentioned there's a translation of the mishna berura, it covers orah haim.
there are some parts but I also didn't find it all translated.

in any case my suggestion is to learn hebrew, even if there was a translation they are not always perfect as a general rule and more so to a book like shulhan aruch that each word is chosen and has dierent impact but no good relections in english, like using אין instead of asur.
what I mean is that using a translation is like asking for someone to read it for you, you can get and idea but you are not really going to the source

Comment: How is one supposed to translate Maran ha-Mechaber's language, e.g.: *yesh lehakel* (*lehachmir/lehachamir*), *ein*, *yesh omrim*, and other things like this?

Comment: There are those who say it can be done ;)