# English version of SHULCHAN ARUCH

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, shulchan-aruch, english

Hi I'm looking for good set of SHULCHAN ARUCH in English, Not K'tzur I need SHULCHAN ARUCH.

Can someone please advise me on set that I can buy ?

Comment: here is some http://www.torah.org/advanced/shulchan-aruch/

Comment: Not online.... and not some :) Thank you anyway

Comment: There is no Sulhan Aruch in English... I got Kitzur in both English and Hebrew, Works just fine :)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7717/759

Comment: Comments [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100207/15571) overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no set of the straight Shulchan Arukh in English. You can find English versions of its commentaries, or sets of Kitzur. But as for just the Shulchan Arukh, you are out of luck.

Comment: A quick Google search shows many mishna brura English translations, and I myself just came across a very good one...which I'll try to find bli neder. While perhaps technically a commentary, it includes a translation of the Shulchan aruch.

Comment: @andrewmh20 That would only cover the _Orach Chayim_ section of the _Shulckan Arukh_, but not the other three sections.

Comment: @TamirEvan true. Hence a comment.

Answer (score 8):

It took several years from the OP but I am pleased to announce that Sefaria has posted most of the original-by-Señor-Yosef-Karo Shulchan Aruch in English: https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Halakhah/Shulchan%20Arukh?lang=bi

Comment: Choshen Mishpat is lacking

Comment: Beit Shmuel as well. But 4 out of 6 sections are fully translated and available for free, not too shabby

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of an English translation that has only the Shulhan Aruch. But the Mishna Brura's translation includes both the Shulhan Aruch and the Chofetz Haim commentary of the SA, see for instance [SeforimCenter.com](http://seforimcenter.com/Mishnah-Berurah--English/Hebrew-Edition-Pisgah-Edition/Mishnah-Berurah---English/Hebrew-Edition-large-size---20-vol.__p-618-1382.aspx)

Comment: That would only cover the _Orach Chayim_ section of the _Shulckan Arukh_, but not the other three sections.

Answer (score 1):

I actually own an old set of 3 volumes,which translate Choshen Mishpat ,alot of Even Haezer and some of Yoreh Deah. Its called Jewish Code of Jurisprudence by Rabb JL Kadushin. If you put in a search you will see some copies are available.

Answer (score 0):

Kehot, the central Chabad-Lubavitch publishing house,  has released an English translation of the Shulchan Aruch HaRav, which you can purchase [here](http://store.kehotonline.com/English/products/460/).

The [Shulchan Aruch HaRav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch_HaRav) is not to be confused with the regular [Shulchan Aruch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch).

Comment: I think he was looking for R' Yosef Karo's shulchan Aruch

Comment: from the publisher: "Notations appear when the Alter Rebbe`s rulings are at variance with Rabbi Yosef Karo`s Shulchan Aruch and when other halachic works cite the subject at hand."

Comment: but it's still not a translation of the (original) shulchan Aruch