# Is there an English Shulchan Aruch Audio online?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, shulchan-aruch

Is there anyone online that gives a straight English  Shulchan Aruch shiur online? Shulchan Aruch not Kitzur Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: This would prob be a good place to look https://www.yutorah.org/search/?s=shulchan+aruch&sort=1

Comment: Considering that Rav Yosef Karo's Shulchan Aruch has never been translated into English as of yet, I doubt such a thing exists.

Comment: @ezra it has, as part of other projects, e.g. [*Mishnah Berurah*](https://zbermanbooks.com/mishnah-berurah-large-20-vol-set).

Comment: Many of it has been translated, yet in many different places,the whole treifos is translated by at least two diff ppl ,almost the whole Choshen Mishpat has been translated a long time ago in 3 vol,melicha basar bchalav  and taarovos has been translated by Rabbi Shenckolweski,there are more these are just the ones that came to mind

Comment: @ezra As sam noted, there are quite a few translations of the SA (though can’t recall if there’s one covering the entire SA). [R. Chaim Denburg](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/denburg-chaim) translated many portions of the SA from the YD and CM sections. Google his books. Aryeh Kaplan translated the laws of Chanukkah, IIRC, as they are in SA.

Comment: For Choshen Mishpat he only did the first 27 chapters @oliver